# Netty client receives the message delay

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

1.scene description:
Device sen data to Netty Server(about ## 20ms intervals ##), Netty Server forward msg to Client ## Immediately ##(IOS or Android).
2.Associated business code
ctx.writeAndFlush(msg)

```
protected void doWrite(ChannelOutboundBuffer in) throws Exception {
    int writeSpinCount = -1;

    boolean setOpWrite = false;
    for (;;) {
        //Get the data of the first node that needs to be flushed
        Object msg = in.current();

        if (msg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            
            ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;

            boolean done = false;
            long flushedAmount = 0;
            // Get the number of spin lock iterations
            if (writeSpinCount == -1) {
                writeSpinCount = config().getWriteSpinCount();
            }
            // Spin, write out the current node
            for (int i = writeSpinCount - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
                int localFlushedAmount = doWriteBytes(buf);
                if (localFlushedAmount == 0) {
                    setOpWrite = true;
                    break;
                }

                flushedAmount += localFlushedAmount;
                if (!buf.isReadable()) {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            in.progress(flushedAmount);

            // After writing, delete the current node
            if (done) {
                in.remove();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

```
protected int doWriteBytes(ByteBuf buf) throws Exception {
    final int expectedWrittenBytes = buf.readableBytes();
    return buf.readBytes(javaChannel(), expectedWrittenBytes);
}
```

3.issue
The netty Server can receive the device data in time
and netty Server can write the data to Socket Buffer in time also.
But The Netty client receives the message delay！！！(eg. 5s delay)

4.Server bandwidth configuration
Inbound 100M/bps bit per seconds.
Outbound 5M/bps bit per seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Client terminal length packer caused by the problem.